# Refresh Excel Pivots via Access DB in Shared Locale

Tags: excel, ms-access

To expand on the title...
My coworker and I work simultaneously on updating the same Access DB and often do so by sending the file back and forth :/

The same goes for when we have to update regular reporting via pivots in Excel that are connected to various tables in the same Access DB.

We tried creating a new shared permissions folder in one of our Onedrives but we (actually just the one person who does not own the Onedrive) cannot refresh the pivots because Excel cannot see the Access DB even though we have pointed the connection (ODBE) to the new location.

Any insights or help would be great.  We are trying to avoid using a Client/Server (SQL or Azure) approach.